# How can I view multiple Chat rooms in one page?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat

I'd like to be in multiple StackExchange chat rooms with just one browser window (or page, or tab). Is there an interface for that? If not, is any work being done in that direction?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do that right now. Each chat room has to be in its own tab or window.

There's no work being done in that direction. Far as I know, you're the first person to bring that up. :)

I personally think trying to fit several active chat rooms into one tab would be distracting at best.

Comment: Distracting, or cause for a bigger screen.

Comment: @tombull89 Distracting. I already have a big screen. :) If you want to fill up a big screen, putting up a few chat windows side by side seems like an easy solution.

Comment: I did that once - even two active rooms side-by-side on a 24" screen was too much. I was agreeing with you it's not really needed.

Comment: I'm not really looking for having them side by side.

Comment: @Sparr Fair, but then I'm having a lot of trouble picturing what you're looking for. How would you combine multiple chatrooms into one window? (Note that we currently show a list of other rooms you're in on the sidebar in chat, so you can switch between them without opening multiple tabs. Although that won't work across chat *servers* - chat.stackoverflow, chat.meta.stackoverflow, chat.stackexchange.)

Comment: @AnnaLear for an example, check out mibbit.com or webchat.freenode.net which are web IRC clients